# Multiple cells' UIButtons seem to be linked

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have a simple UIButton linked up to my cell, the weird part it that when I select it and scroll down a bit, it seems that it also is selected for another cell. They are separated by even distances, so if I like two cells, further down, two other cells will have their buttons selected as well.

[image]

I've included the code for the button, but all other of my buttons don't seem to act this way. I MAY have to implement a dictionary to see if that'll help.

@IBAction func UpButton(sender: AnyObject) {

```
    var button = sender as! DOFavoriteButton

    if button.selected == true{
        let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
        let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
        let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)
        object.incrementKey("count", byAmount: -1)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        object.saveInBackground()
    }
    else
    {
        let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
        let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
        let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)
        object.incrementKey("count", byAmount: 1)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        object.saveInBackground()



}
```

Comment: Since cells get reused when scrolling, you will need to clear any UI state in the cell in its prepareForReuse. And also you should never do any computations based on UI state, instead should rely on states in corresponding model objects